# Can´t commit changes with Xcode and Bitbucket?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, xcode10

i want to commit and push my changes to bitbucket directly in xcode. I switched to a new mac so I had to do all the things again (SSH-Key etc.) everything is working except that for Xcode. See the error message here

[image]

[image]

[image: heres the id_rsa it´s in my home tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tapped on login and i choosed ssh Key and i choosed id_rsa then it worked as normal

Answer (score 0):

If you select "https" for cloning, while your credentials are an SSH keys... that won't work.

Try first and select SSH in your BitBucket Account setting, to give a chance for your SSH URL `git@bitbucket.org:...` to be resolved correctly.

Comment: @SwiftNewling It was not on SSH in your screenshot.

Comment: Yea i mean i´ve set it yesterday to ssh and tried which hasn´t worked, so i changed back. Same error message

Comment: @SwiftNewling OK. I can guarantee that https won't work with an SSH key, though.

Comment: Does a `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` work from command line? Can you try in XCode settings to specify the full path of `id_rsa`, for testing?

Comment: I did the command line. and yes i can specify. Check the Question at the top again

Comment: @SwiftNewling That is why I asked you to specify the full path of the private key: in case it could help.

Comment: Only that screenshot in the question